# Can I using default ubuntu 1804's appearance on ubuntu 1604?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I am a ubuntu desktop user. I really get used to Ubuntu 1804's default apperence.

For example: The bottom to close window is at the right up corner. The bottom to show all application is at the left down corner. etc.

However, recently, I must use a software which only support 16.04.
So I had to go back to 16.04.

I wonder that if can I do some configure to make my 1604 have defalut 1804's apperence?  I mean, when I see from the apperence, oh, it is 1804.

I apologize if it is a stupid problems. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No stupid problems, just silly answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses the [Unity Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)) (not to be confused with the later [Unity game engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) on top of the [GNOME3](https://www.gnome.org/) environment.

Ubuntu switched back to the [GNOME3 Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME#GNOME_3) in fall of 2017. That's why they look different.

How to switch 16.04LTS to use the GNOME3 Desktop?  As per https://thelinuxcode.com/install-gnome-desktop-environment-ubuntu-16-04/ do these commands at a shell prompt in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt install gnome && sudo reboot
```

Once the system reboots, you will see your normal login prompt. At the upper right of its dialog box there's an Ubuntu icon in a circle. Click on that and choose a GNOME3 login.

There's more detail at https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts